# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `projects` set `0` = 16770463651676465776.jpg,

Tags: laravel

I want to update record but this error occur and I don't have a 0 column in anywhere in my code.

Here is controller Code:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'start_date' => 'required',
            'end_date' => 'required',
            'project_type' => 'required',
            'material' =>'required',
            'material.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);


        if ($request->id)
        {
            if ($request->file('material') == '')
            {
                $data = Project::where('id', $request->id)->first();
                $input['material'] = $data->material;
            }else {
                if($request->hasfile('material')){
                    $input = [];
                    foreach($request->file('material') as $file)
                    {
                        $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
                        $file->move(public_path().'/image/project/'.$name);
                        $input[]= $name;
                        array_push($input, $name);
                    }
                }
            }
            $input['name'] = $request->name;
            $input['start_date'] = $request->start_date;
            $input['end_date'] = $request->end_date;
            $input['amount'] = $request->amount;
            $input['notes'] = $request->notes;
            $input['api'] = $request->api;
            $input['project_type'] = $request->project_type;
            $input['domain'] = $request->domain;
            $input['content_type'] = $request->content_type;
            $input['content_description'] = $request->content_description;


            $data = Project::where('id', $request->id)->update($input);
            return back()->with('success', 'Updated Successfully!');

        }
```

This is my controller code I want to update record with multiple images, but this error come and i don't update the record.

Comment: your `$input` array has the key 0 while you are trying to add multiple images to the `$input` array, do `dd($input);` before updating to check it out. How are you handling the multiple images in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a key for this line

```
$input[]= $name;
```

like

```
$input['file_name']= $name;
```